# Facebook share problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey. The code below is used to share something on Facebook. But when I click the share button it is opening new window.

I don't want this. I want open a new div. How can I do?

```
<script>
function fbs_click()
{
    u=location.href;
    t=document.title;
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
    return false;
}
</script>
<style> 
    html .fb_share_link { padding:2px 0 0 20px; height:16px; background:url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat top left; }
</style>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" class="fb_share_link">
    Facebook'ta paylaş
</a>
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that the share is being dropped or something like that, and instead you should use the `Like` button

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Facebook Share always force a new window?

Or are you looking for the modal window that Facebook uses on its website? If so, I believe you need to use the API for that.

If that is indeed the case, I recommend taking their Developer Resources with a pinch of salt. It's out dated and misleading. Check out http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
       function fbs_click()
       {
           $('.DivSai').show();
           return false;
       }
</script>

</head>
<body style="font-size: 100%;">
    <div class="DivSai" style="display: none;">
        <iframe src="Default.aspx" runat="server"></iframe>
    </div>

    <a rel="nofollow" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return fbs_click()"  class="fb_share_link">
    Facebook'ta paylaş
</a>
</body>
```